# Ansible installs the Windows patch successfully but yet exits with fail code

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

```
fatal: [hostname.domain]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "wusa.exe C:\\Temp\\Windows8.1-KB3042553-x64.msu /quiet /norestart", "delta": "0:00:00.109333", "end": "2017-04-11 04:57:09.337190", "failed": true, "rc": 5, "start": "2017-04-11 04:57:09.227857", "stderr": "", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
fatal: [hostname.domain]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "wusa.exe C:\\Temp\\Windows8.1-KB3042553-x64.msu /quiet /norestart", "delta": "0:00:00.281051", "end": "2017-04-11 04:57:09.321305", "failed": true, "rc": 5, "start": "2017-04-11 04:57:09.040254", "stderr": "", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
```

Playbook below.

```
 - hosts: all

   tasks:
       - name: Copy Patch from Control machine
         win_copy:
           src: /tmp/win_updates/
           dest: C:\Temp\

       - name: Extracting Patch on local machine
         win_command: wusa.exe C:\Temp\Windows8.1-KB3042553-x64.msu /extract:C:\Temp

       - name: Installing the Patch on local machine
         win_command: dism.exe /online /add-package /PackagePath:C:\Temp\Windows8.1-KB3042553-x64.cab /NoRestart /quiet
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not an ansible problem, but wusa one. Judging by exit code 5, and [this MS doc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2773898/windows-update-standalone-installer-wusa-returns-0x5-error-access-denied-when-deploying-.msu-files-through-winrm-and-windows-remote-shell)

> Installing an update using WUSA or the WUA APIs on a remote machine is not supported.

And ansible uses PowerShell remoting to manage Windows hosts.

See also:

- https://superuser.com/questions/894826/invoke-command-using-wusa-exe-in-powershell-wont-install-the-msu
- [What does wusa.exe return code 5 mean?](https://serverfault.com/questions/559287/what-does-wusa-exe-return-code-5-mean)